# display an image in canvas view using Xamarin.Forms

Tags: xamarin.forms

On using

```
canvasview = SKCanvasView();
canvas.createBitmap (bitmap,info.Rect) // i used for drawing image
```

new surface displayed without image.

It's getting empty blank screen.

Answer (score 0):

Once the NuGets are installed, you can add the SkiaSharp view to the XAML. Here, we’re adding a SKCanvasView, the CPU-based drawing surface, but you could also use the SKGLView, the GPU-based drawing surface:

```
<ContentPage ... xmlns:views="clr-namespace:SkiaSharp.Views.Forms;assembly=SkiaSharp.Views.Forms">
  <Grid>
    <views:SKCanvasView PaintSurface="OnPainting" />
  </Grid>
</ContentPage>
```

Then add the event handler in the code-behind for the page:

```
using SkiaSharp;
using SkiaSharp.Views.Forms;

private void OnPainting(object sender, SKPaintSurfaceEventArgs e)
{
  // we will draw here
}
```

For more detail about `SkiaSharp` you can refer the [blog](https://blog.xamarin.com/drawing-with-skiasharp/).
And here is a [sample](https://github.com/mono/SkiaSharp/tree/master/samples/Basic/Xamarin.Forms/SkiaSharpSample)

Comment: xaml link : https://i.stack.imgur.com/n1LQi.png & .cs file link: https://i.stack.imgur.com/9ZSkI.png